# using two lists how to calculate the min price between two elements in one list using second list as a reference?

Tags: python

I was asked this question during a Python coding interview and wasn't able to code it right.
There are two lists:

```
islands=[isl_1, isl_2, isl_3, isl_4] 
tickets=[0, 100, 200, 300, 2, 0, 25, 170, 10, 20, 0, 300, 540, 80, 60, 0]
```

Each 4 items in the in tickets list is the price for the island: `isl_1` to `isl_2 = 100`, `isl_1` to `isl_3 = 200` and so on. How to write a function that will calculate the cheapest way from `from_isl` to `to_isl`?

```
def cheapest_ticket(from_isl, to_isl) --> return min price
```

Comment: There is no shortcut.  The only way to solve it is brute force -- check all of the possibilities.  With 4 islands, there aren't that many.  1->3 could either be 1->3 or 1->2->3 or 1->4->3 or 1->2->4->3.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the same concept as in [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) but should be a [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) e.g. isl_1->isl_2 is 100 but isl_2->isl_1 is just 2. Here is a pseudocode:

1. Construct the directed and weighted graph.

   - This will be your network map between all islands, where each path has the information about the `(direction, price)`.
   - To emphasize, isl_1->isl_2 will be a different path to isl_2->isl_1
2. Now given a starting point `from_isl`, traverse the path using the usual graph algorithms up until you reach `to_isl`.

   - Note that unlike [breadth-first_search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), you shouldn't stop once you reached `to_isl` the first time. You should continue up until all islands are visited because chances are the shortest path e.g. isl_1->isl_2 isn't the least price, probably the longer isl_1->isl_4->isl_2 has a lesser price.

     - So I think [depth-first_search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) would be preferred. We should mark what is visited and what isn't yet for each of the different possible paths that would lead to `to_isl` (same concept as [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) where after isl1->isl3->isl2 we would then explore isl1->isl3->isl4->isl2 and so on). Note that as with BFS, don't stop once `to_isl` is reached the first time, all possible paths should still be explored.
   - For each traversed path, make sure to sum up the total `price` at that point.
   - Once all islands are visited, stop the traversals. Then, compare the least price among those paths that lead to `to_isl` e.g. isl_1->isl_2 vs isl_1->isl_4->isl_2 vs isl_1->isl_3->isl_4->isl2 etc.

Comment: Since Dijsktra’s algorithm uses a priority queue, you can actually stop once your destination becomes the current node. The only exceptions come up if you’re doing certain optimizations like bidirectional search.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations

cost_matrix = [[0, 100, 200, 300], [2, 0, 25, 170], [10, 20, 0, 300], [540, 80, 60, 0]]

base = [1, 2, 3, 4]
all_paths = []
for x in base:
    if x > 1:
        perm = permutations(base, x)
        for i in list(perm):
            all_paths.append(i)
# print(all_paths)


def get_paths(start, finish):
    print(f"Going from island {start} to island {finish}")
    return list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == start and x[-1] == finish, all_paths))


def get_costs(paths):
    prices = []
    for path in paths:
        price = sum(
            map(lambda x: cost_matrix[x[0] - 1][x[1] - 1], zip(path[:-1], path[1:]))
        )
        prices.append(price)
    return prices


I = input("Enter start,finish > ")
[start, finish] = list(map(int, I.split(",")))
paths = get_paths(start, finish)
print("Possible paths", paths)
costs = get_costs(paths)
print("Path costs", costs)
print("Min value", min(costs))
i = costs.index(min(costs))
print("cheapest path:", paths[i])
```

I start by getting all the paths between a and b, noting that a -> b != b-> a.
I filter this to give me the paths between the selected islands,
Then I ask the cost matrix what a path segment costs and add them up.
Then I pick the cheapest path. This code can be refactored into a single function but I wanted to show my working so you could follow it.

Comment: Thank you very much - it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

The given question can be solved using the following approach.

1. We find out all the possible paths when given a start and end. We filter out start and end from the given array, in this case, a list of islands, to reduce complexity. We insert those at the end.
2. Find price mapping from one node to every other node.
3. Find the minimum price between paths now.

Adding the following code, hope it helps.

```
import json
from itertools import permutations

islands = ["isl_1", "isl_2", "isl_3", "isl_4"]
tickets = [0, 100, 200, 300, 2, 0, 25, 170, 10, 20, 0, 300, 540, 80, 60, 0]

def get_island_to_island_price_mapping():
    island_to_island_price_mapping = {}

    island_start = 0
    island_end = len(islands)


    for island in islands:
        index = 0
        for price in tickets[island_start:island_end]:
            island_to_island_price_mapping[island+'--->'+islands[index]] = price
            index += 1
        island_start += len(islands)
        island_end += len(islands)

    print("island_to_island_price_mapping ---->", json.dumps(island_to_island_price_mapping, indent=4))
    return island_to_island_price_mapping

def get_all_possible_paths(array, start, finish):
    all_paths = []
    array.remove(start)
    array.remove(finish)
    for index in range(len(array)+1):
        path_object = permutations(array, index)
        for path in path_object:
            actual_path = list(path)
            actual_path.insert(0, start)
            actual_path.append(finish)
            all_paths.append(actual_path)
    print("ALL PATHS ---->", json.dumps(all_paths, indent=4))
    return all_paths


def get_minimum_price_path():
    price_mapping = get_island_to_island_price_mapping()
    paths = get_all_possible_paths(islands,'isl_1','isl_4')
    price_to_path_map = {}

    for path_permuations in paths:
        price = 0
        for index in range(1, len(path_permuations)):
            price += price_mapping[path_permuations[index-1]+'--->'+path_permuations[index]]
        price_to_path_map[price] = '--->'.join(path_permuations)
    print("price_to_path_map---->", json.dumps(price_to_path_map, indent=4))

    return price_to_path_map[min(price_to_path_map.keys())]


minimum_price_path = get_minimum_price_path()
```

Comment: @Mike L Please accept my answer if you find it useful